# Python - Collect data from specific column in file

Tags: python

I need help with this query/question...

How can i collect data from specific column in file, like this:

```
**[FILE.txt]**

CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
CODE \t USERNAME \t SPENT \t COLUM1 \t COLUM2
```

Remember...This is examples of users in this files... Every user can have diferent values on SPENT...

I'll put the values of user1,user2,user3 in a accumulator.

So...how can i proceed?

**SOLVED WITH**

```
lines = open("database").readlines()
quantidade = 0
for i in range(3):
    line = lines[i].split('\t')
    quantidade = quantidade + int(line[2])
print "Quantidade de Produtos Comprados: ",quantidade
#for line in range (10):
#   line = lines[-2].split() #Gets the second last value from the list and split on whitespace
#   print line

raw_input("Precione 'ENTER' para voltar ao menu principal... ")
return
```

Comment: Sorry but, i dont found any like this...

Comment: Use for loop with split method.

Comment: Dont Working... =/

 lines = open("database").readlines()
 for line in range (10):
  line = lines[-2].split() #Gets the second last value from the list and split on whitespace
  print line

Comment: try this method which iterates over the file:

    colnum = 2 # spent
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            do_something(line.split('\t')[colnum])

Comment: I guarantee the split works here. Try to work it out!

Comment: hint: for lines in infile: lines = lines.split("\t") After this you can call the SPENT column by lines[2]

Comment: Solved with  lines = open("database").readlines()
 quantidade = 0
 for i in range(3):
  line = lines[i].split('\t')
  quantidade = quantidade + int(line[2])
 print "Quantidade de Produtos Comprados: ",quantidade
 #for line in range (10):
 # line = lines[-2].split() #Gets the second last value from the list and split on whitespace
 # print line

 raw_input("Precione 'ENTER' para voltar ao menu principal... ")
 return